# how to send the array from android to php?

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to insert this this array into mysql table so I'm using php.

For example I want to insert the checked items form checkbox and I already store it in an array like this

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");
```

how do to send this to php?

and how do the php receive the array?
does the usual $__GET works?

```
$arr = $_GET['resultArr[]'];
```

thanks before, sorry for my bad english

Comment: `$arr = $_REQUEST['resultArr']; var_dump($arr);` try this

Answer (score 0):

You can create `JSON` of data which you want to send ..and at php you can parse that `JSON` to retrieve your data for that refer this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)